# how to use MySQL code directly into a Yii query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I have this MySQL insert:

```
INSERT INTO restaurant (id_restaurant, id_category)
SELECT id_rest, id_cat
FROM restaurant_menu rm, category_menu cm
WHERE rm.name = "discount" AND cm.name = "beach";
```

but now I want to do this insert in Yii. I know that I can do it using [Yii query builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder), but I think that if the query/insert/delete/update is very long, that is too complex. Therefore, I would like to know if is possible to use MySQL code into a Yii code directly, I mean, for example something similar to this:

```
$sql='INSERT INTO restaurant (id_restaurant, id_category) SELECT id_rest, id_cat FROM restaurant_menu rm, category_menu cm WHERE rm.name = "discount" AND cm.name = "beach"'

$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
```

Please, someone could show me how to do this insert using the MySQL code directly in Yii?

Comment: Careful with your quoting in your second example. If you're using `"` for your string, use `'` for your data. Or better, use placeholder values.

Comment: Thanks @user2989514. I have just corrected the code. Am I using right the ""  and '' now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have it right:

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;
$command=$connection->createCommand($sqlStatement);
$command->execute();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection

Comment: Thanks @Pitchinnate. I understand that $sqlStatement in my case is $sql, is it right?

Comment: Yes the name of the variable is arbitrary it could be anything.